# I do not fit the image I received from the user in Android studio fully into the imageview

Tags: java, android, android-studio

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MfgLU.jpg)

this is my application. I want the images in this recycler view to fill the whole screen. As in Instagram (I set the width of the Image View to match parent)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4KrwM.jpg)

I want it to look like this

Answer (score 0):

try setting your imageview width to 0dp and if this doesn't work then try setting scaleType to fitXY.
Let me know if this works or not!

Answer (score 0):

Try using `adjustViewBounds` attribute, also you can use `scaleType` attribute if you want to scale the image:

```
<ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />
```